# Copy All Script on Forum HTML TextBox

Tags: javascript, html, forum

I am trying to code a HTML text box, with a button to COPY all the text contents of a particular div class.

The code does copy text, however, it copys text from the entire page (multiple posts on a forum) instead of the one post of interest. Is there a way to stop it doing this?

My code below so far, 
Many Thanks for your help

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="codebox">   
      <div class="ipsCode_citation">
        <div style="float:right">
          <button onclick="copyText()">Copy</button>
        </div>
        Code:
      </div>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div id="output"></div>

<script>
  function copyText(){
    var outputText = "";
    var targets = document.getElementsByClassName('codebox');
    for (var i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
      outputText += targets[i].innerText;
    }
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.innerText = outputText;
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(output);
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
    document.execCommand('copy');
    output.style.display = 'none';
  }
</script>
```

In an attempt to apply Matt Webbs suggestion. Is this on the correct lines?

```html
<div class="codebox">   
  <div>
    <button class="codeBtn">Copy</button>
  </div>
<p>&nbsp;</p> Some text to copy
</div>

<script>

var copyBtn = document.querySelector('.codeBtn');

copyBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var copyText = document.querySelector('.codebox');
  copyText.select();

  var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
});

</script>
```

Comment: Are you just trying to copy the text to the id `output`?

Comment: Hi Matt. I am trying to copy text contained in that single instance of the div class code box (not all the instances on the webpage) to the clipboard so I can paste it in another program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample of what you need, this will copy the contents within `.codebox` to the clip board.

HTML

```
<div>
  <textarea class="codebox">function helloWorld() {}</textarea>
</div>

<div>
  <button class="codeBtn">Copy</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
var copyBtn = document.querySelector('.codeBtn');

copyBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var copyText = document.querySelector('.codebox');
  copyText.select();

  var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
});
```

Sample:
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Webby2014/zjzw419L/)

### UPDATE

To get the text (or html) form the specific area where the button is, using the html you have provided, you can do something like this, notice I have used a hidden `textarea` so we can still utilise the `document.execCommand('copy')`:

HTML

```
<div class="codebox">
  <div class="ipsCode_citation">
    <div style="float:right">
      <button class="codeBtn">Copy</button>
    </div>
    Code:
    <textarea style="display:none" id="hidden-codebox"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var copyBtn = document.querySelector('.codeBtn');

copyBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // copy element text:
  var copyText = document
    .querySelector('.codeBtn') // button
    .parentElement // div
    .parentElement // div.ipsCode_citation
    .parentElement.innerText; // div.codebox

  // push to HIDDEN textarea:
  var hiddenCode = document.getElementById('hidden-codebox');
  hiddenCode.value = copyText;
  hiddenCode.select();

  try {
    var status = document.execCommand('copy');
    if (!status) {
      console.error("Cannot copy text");
    } else {
      console.log("The text is now on the clipboard");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Unable to copy.');
  }
});
```

Sample:
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Webby2014/ap07y8ft/2/)

Comment: Hello, this won't work exactly though, since the OP's problem is that it copies from the whole page.

Comment: Thanks for the example, I would prefer to not use textarea as I have some custom CSS for the codebox I have created. Are textarea class and div class interchangeable?

@LFlare, From what google turned up, the queryselector method only seems to return the first instance (which may or may work from my applicaton)

Comment: @Calico I have updated my answer which includes a more dynamic way to attain the text, using the button as a reference point.

Comment: @MattWebb Thanks for the update. It doesnt seem to be working on my end. Please see my attached fiddle with CSS added. I've added sample text to copy, does it work for you? https://jsfiddle.net/Caleeco/zyjumweL/

Comment: @Calico This is working for me. Are you specifically trying to copy this data to the clipboard? What are actually trying to do?

Comment: @MattWebb Thanks for getting back to me. Yes, I'm trying to copy the inner text to clipboard. The idea being, on my forum people will post VBA code they need help with using the HTML codebox described, then for the forum to help troubleshoot, I wanted to add a copy text button so they could quickly copy the posted VBA to clipboard and paste it to the Excel VBA application where they could make edits in the native environment. Hopefully that makes sense?

Comment: @Calico hi, I have updated my code. In order for this to copy the details to the clipboard you need some form of input control, I have therefore combined my answers so it uses a hidden textarea. Check out the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Webby2014/ap07y8ft/2/

Comment: @MattWebb, spot on! Works a treat, thank you for your assistance, it's much appreciated! Marked Solved